# Add elements in ObjectList in Java using CORBA

Tags: java, corba, idl

I have an unbounded sequence in the IDL file as follows :

```
struct Info {
            string name;
        };

typedef sequence<Info> InfoList;

InfoList search(in short length);
```

ServantClass present in server implments the interface as follows.

```
public Info[] search(short length) {

 Info[] infolist;

 for(int i =0; i<= length; i++) {
    /*
     *  I want to add/push a 'name' into infolist.
     *  may be something like infolist.push()
     */

 }

}
```

How can I push name elements into the info objet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the name to `Info's` constructor

```
@Override
public Info[] search(short length) {
    Info[] infolist = new Info[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < infolist.length; i++) {
        infolist[i] = new Info("New Name");
    }

    return infolist;
}
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I keep getting a nullpointer exception.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at FileObj.search(FileObj.java:96)
 at SearchApp.FileOperationInterfacePOA._invoke(FileOperationInterfacePOA.java:52)
 at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(Unknown Source)
 ... 10 more

Comment: line no. 96 is the the following line `    holder.value.name = "New Name";`

Comment: holder.value is null at the point where holder.value.name is assigned. This technique is completely pointless.

Comment: @Reimeus any good books you can suggest me to solve these complex problem.

Comment: @TheThird There is nothing complex about this problem.